# Traceback error in terminal when trying to use python

Tags: python, traceback

I am getting this error whenever I try to use terminal. I was initially trying to use pip to install html5lib, but now I can't even use python. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ DanLee$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in     <module> 
import os
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 49, in <module>
import posixpath as path
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 450, in  <module>
plt.plot(years,gdp, color = 'green', marker = 'o', linestyle = 'solid')
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
Dans-MacBook-Pro:~ DanLee$ pip install html5lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
import os
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 49, in <module>
import posixpath as path
File "/Users/DanLee/anaconda/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 450, in <module>
plt.plot(years,gdp, color = 'green', marker = 'o', linestyle = 'solid')
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Use Terminal to execute a Python script or just install modules?

Comment: I am trying to install modules, particularly trying to run pip install html5lib to get a web parser.

Comment: What is the output of the following commands:
`$ which python`
`$ env | sort`

Comment: /Users/DanLee/anaconda/bin/python       /usr/bin/env

Comment: If you really need to use the Anaconda distribution, and do not want to install the standard python implementation and then install all the modules that Anaconda comes with, I would recommend just reinstalling Anaconda and starting from scratch.

Comment: After doing that, will I be able to pip install html5lib? I don't think Anaconda comes with it.

Comment: Install PIP using Conda with `conda install pip` then install html5lib with `pip install html5lib`

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing comments here:

You've installed Anaconda, so use `conda` to install packages:

```
conda install html5lib
```

Of course, it seems you've somehow messed up your Anaconda install, so re-install it first.